# Jquery accordion doesnt work when using HTML Table tags

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, mysql

Can someone please help me understand why this fiddle doesnt work? Where it lists section 1 should be the header to click on and where the wording is, should be the dropdown. It doesnt display properly however. Is there something with the HTML and using a table?

https://jsfiddle.net/x3r0Lmwe/

Section 1

```
    Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
    ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
    amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
    odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
```

Comment: Your htmls are invalid .Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/bL5xw2fg/) out.